# Best use of content_tag in a custom link_to helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What is the best way to use a custom helper method in order to generate html tags with links and html options?

lets say

```
def drop_document_options(title,document,version,html_options)


end
```

in order to generate a link with the parameters:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">

<%=@hebrew_document[document]%>  - <%=@hebrew_version[version]%>

<span class="caret"></span></button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

  <li> <%=link_to( {:controller => "invoices",
                      :action => "download",
                      :id => document.id,
                      :disposition => 'inline',
                      :version => version[i]} ,
                      html_options )  do %>

                      <%=action_title%>
    <% end %>

   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a partial looks easier then using a helper in this case

Comment: Check `rake routes` for the named url helper rails already offers you for your link. Pretty sure you can then use something like `link_to action_title, download_invoices_path(document, disposition: inline, version: version[i], html_options)`.

Comment: Baldrick, post it as answer please, edit it so it contains a def that takes params, and renders it with partial variables, I will accept it